# Error blocked loading of Jquery.js - Content Security Policy

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, content-security-policy, nonce

I am getting below error while loading application:

```
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“script-src”). jquery-3.6.0.js:6333:7
```

code at this line:

> ```
> if ( elem.nodeType === 1 ) {
>       jQuery.cleanData( getAll( elem, false ) );
>       elem.innerHTML = value;    // this line is causing issue
>   }
> ```

My CSP header:

```
add_header Content-Security-Policy    "default-src 'self' data: blob: ;
                                        script-src 'self' data: blob: 'nonce-2726c7f26c';
                                        style-src 'self' data: blob: ;
                                        img-src 'self' ;
                                        form-action 'self' ;
                                        frame-ancestors 'self' ;" always;
```

I am trying to use 'nonce' also but it is not working.

```
<script src="js/jquery-3.6.0.js" nonce="2726c7f26c"></script>
```

I don't want to use 'unsafe-inline'.
Can anyone please help to fix this issue, I have spent 2 days in googling but nothing works out.
Thanks in Advance.

Update 1:
In Chrome below errors are coming:

> jquery-3.6.0.js:6262 Refused to apply inline style because it violates
> the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self'
> data: blob: 'nonce-2726c7f26c'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a
> hash ('sha256-1PxuDsPyGK6n+LZsMv0gG4lMX3i3XigG6h0CzPIjwrE='), or a
> nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
>
> (anonymous) @ jquery-3.6.0.js:6262 domManip @ jquery-3.6.0.js:6089
> prepend @ jquery-3.6.0.js:6259 (anonymous) @ angular.min.js:315
>
> :81/uploadGrp:1  Refused to execute inline event handler because it
> violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src
> 'self' data: blob: 'nonce-2726c7f26c'". Either the 'unsafe-inline'
> keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required
> to enable inline execution. Note that hashes do not apply to event
> handlers, style attributes and javascript: navigations unless the
> 'unsafe-hashes' keyword is present.

Code at line jquery-3.6.0.js:6262:

```
if ( this.nodeType === 1 || this.nodeType === 11 || this.nodeType === 9 ) {
     var target = manipulationTarget( this, elem );
     target.insertBefore( elem, target.firstChild ); //this line is causing issue.
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jquery 3.6 [redistributes 'nonce-value'](https://csplite.com/csp/test379/#jQuery_3.x) it into all inline scripts it injected, including `scriptAttrs: {nonce: "value"}` attribute in `$.ajax()`. Therefore the line:

> `elem.innerHTML = value;    // this line is causing issue`

contains inline event handler (eg `<tag onclick='...'`) or javascript navigation (eg `<a href='javascript:void()'`) or even `<script>...</script>` in the 'value'.

The Firefox browser is not much verbose to differ these kinds of inline scripts, but Chrome will dfescribe violations more prescribely (`Refused to execute inline script` / `Refused to execute inline event handler` / `Refused to run the JavaScript URL`). Therefore using Chrome you can shred a lights whats going on.

Alternatively you can use reporting facilities of Content Security Policy (CSP) - add `'report-sample'` token into `script-src` directive and add `report-uri https://url_to_handle_reports;` directive at the end of your CSP (for example you can temporary use a free plan of https://report-uri.com, or use some [Node.js packages](https://csplite.com/csp214/#csp_reports_NodeJS) to handle violation reports).
With a `'report-sample'` token you'll get a sample of code caused violation (first 40 chars).

After identifying the code causing the violation, you can already try to fix it.

**Update** after Chrome console messages been attached

> jquery-3.6.0.js:6262 Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' data: blob: 'nonce-2726c7f26c'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-1PxuDsPyGK6n+LZsMv0gG4lMX3i3XigG6h0CzPIjwrE=') ...

The 'sha256-1PxuDsPyGK6n+LZsMv0gG4lMX3i3XigG6h0CzPIjwrE=' hash relates to typical [block of `<style>` of Angular](https://csplite.com/csp315/#sha256-1PxuDsPyGK6n+LZsMv0gG4lMX3i3XigG6h0CzPIjwrE=) framework.

Jquery does not redistribute `'nonce-value'` from scripts to styles. Anyway Angular requires `'unsafe-inline'` in the `style-src` directive - pls see Suggested Steps: 1. [We should clearly state that allowing 'unsafe-inline' in style-src is required for Angular applications](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/37631).

> :81/uploadGrp:1 Refused to execute **inline event handler** because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' data: blob: 'nonce-2726c7f26c'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...') ...

You do insert inline event handler like `elem.innerHTML = "<div onclick='...'"`. This require `'unsafe-inline'` in the `'script-src'`, because built-in event handlers are covered by `'unsafe-hashes'` token but it's not supported in Safari.

If you can change a logic and use `addEventListener` to attach event handler:

```
document.querySelector("#element-id").addEventListener("click", function() {...do something...} );
```

you can avoid using `'unsafe-inline'` in `script-src`.

BTW: you can to define what event handler is blocked by using a piece of code:

```
if ('SecurityPolicyViolationEvent' in window)
  document.addEventListener('securitypolicyviolation', (e) => {
     console.log(e.sample + '` in `' + e.violatedDirective + '`');
  } );
else console.log('SecurityPolicyViolationEvent unsupported');
```